# Submit Hadoop Jar through Java program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. Our team is writing a hadoop job scheduler. Currently I have hadoop well installed. I can submit Hadoop job in the command line using

```
hadoop jar wordcount.jar input output
```

Now I want to run this command in a java program. In other words, using java to do the same thing as `hadoop jar wordcount.jar input output`. Is there any API I can call to submit jobs from Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) to execute arbitrary system commands

EDIT: The solution I proposed is to just launch the hadoop command as you have specified. Hadoop does have an API for launching jobs, discussed in [Calling a mapreduce job from a simple java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program).

Comment: Updated to add an alternative.

Comment: Could you please show me some example code? Thank you very much.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java. Give something a try - if you have specific questions, post them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Acually I check the API you mentioned. But I am not sure whether it is what I am looking for. In the Job API, the user can specify Mapper class, reduce class, etc. But in my case, we do not care about it. Everything is already packaged in the JAR file. We simply throw it to Hadoop like using "hadoop jar wordcount.jar input output"

Comment: user3034824, i want same thing  as you said  : Everything is already packaged in the JAR file. We simply throw it to Hadoop like using "hadoop jar wordcount.jar input output. If you get answer than tell me. please.