# Start mapreduce job on hadoop 2.2 (Yarn) from java application

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to call a mapreduce job from a java application. In former hadoop versions (1.x) I created a Configuration object and a Job object, set *mapred.job.tracker* and *fs.default.name* in the Configuration and ran the Job. Now, in hadoop 2.x the *job tracker* does not exist anymore neither exists there any documentation on how to programatically run MR1 jobs. Any ideas?

What I'm looking for is an explaination as given here: [Calling a mapreduce job from a simple java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MR Client API is the same for the Legacy MR and YARN. The properties can be set on the Configuration object instead of specifying in the xml configuration files. Check the documentation and the required configurations [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) and [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-nextgen-mapreduce.html) to setup and execute a simple MR job in YARN.

Comment: Hi Praveen, thank your for your answer. I set up a cluster succesfully and ran jobs from command line. No problems so far. But my question was how to start a job from a java application, not from command line.

Comment: As I mentioned the same way you do it for the legacy MR, the API is the same. But, the configuration parameters are different (instead of JT use RM and others) which are specified in the links mentioned in the response.

Comment: Hi Praveen, thank you now I got it. I was confused by the new YarnClient Class and the explanation here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html