# Hadoop - set custom jdk path/version in job configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a mapreduce jar file that requires JDK 1.8 and a Hadoop cluster that has JDK 1.7 installed and configured.

Is it possible to run my jar without changing the Hadoop configuration (i.e. no change to hadoop-env.sh)?

All of the Hadoop nodes also have access to JDK 1.8 and I can easily change JAVA_HOME to point to JDK 1.8 but that does not seem to have any effect without changes to the Hadoop environment variables.

I have already looked at [submitting Hadoop job with ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676157/mapreduce-job-submission-through-java-processbuilder-do-not-ending) and [running mapreduce job from simple Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program) but it's not clear from that how to deal with the job configuration that you normally have.
For instance, I am using this to run my Hadoop job:

```
hadoop jar MyJar.jar -libjars somelibrary.jar input_folder output_folder
```

and I have my main class (which is the entry point already configured in the manifest of the jar) that performs the job configuration as such:

```
public class MyJobMapReduce extends Configured implements Tool {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyJobMapReduce(), args);
        System.exit(res);
 }

 @Override
 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Configuration conf = this.getConf();

     Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "myjob");
     String inputPath = args[0];
     String outputPath = args[1];
     String inputType = args[2];
     boolean readFolder = Boolean.valueOf(args[3]);
     boolean compressOutput = Boolean.valueOf(args[4]);

     job.setNumReduceTasks(50);
     // input
     if (readFolder)
         FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputPath));
     job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

     // output
     job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));
     if (compressOutput) {
         FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
         FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
     }

     // entry point
     job.setJarByClass(MyMapReduce.class);      


     // mapper
     job.setMapperClass(BuildSyntacticTreeMapper.class);
     job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
     // reducer
     job.setReducerClass(DataDumpReducer.class);
     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

     return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
 }
```

}

P.S. my job requires JDK 1.8 because one of the libraries that I am using with -libjars requires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find out that this actually doesn't require any change to my program or any custom java launcher. What helped the most was [How to run a jar file in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012511/how-to-run-a-jar-file-in-hadoop) and determining what the **hadoop jar** part of my command

```
hadoop jar MyJar.jar -libjars somelibrary.jar input_folder output_folder
```

actually did, which was just to set the classpath. 
Therefore, to run a jar in hadoop, with a different java version than the one configured in hadoop-env.sh:

```
hadoop classpath
```

the output is then used in combination with the custom java location, resulting in

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -cp {output from hadoop classpath command}:/path/to/MyJar.jar com.my.SomeClass -libjars somelibrary.jar input_folder output_folder
```