# Running MapReduce applications on Apache YARN using Java Client

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I want to run MapReduce application on a YARN cluster using Java client code. For example, I want to submit WordCount, which resides in `hadoop-examples.jar` file to a YARN cluster of 16 machines using Java APIs.

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html), but I did not get what is the application master jar. Is it the same as `hadoop-examples.jar`? Or another jar contains the ApplicationMaster logic?

I appreciate if you have a Java client code example from a to z to submit MapReduce application to YARN.

**Update:**

What am I intersted to know is to submit MapReduce job as Yarn application using Yarn APIs (e.g. YarnClient, ApplicationClientProtocol, ...) which is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how much this will help with the word count but I have constructed my own personal mappers and reducers that will process R scripts. Without all the complexities here is how I submit a simple job.

The ArtisanJob is just a class that extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job. It has some extra methods for my functionality. You could replace ArtisanJob with just org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job and it should work just fine for you.

My ArtisanConfiguration extends the import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration and could be replaced also with just the import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.

The MetricInputFormat, MetricOutputFormat are the same they are simple adapters that extend InputFormat and OutputFormat respectively.

Let me know if you have any questions, but this is working code for hadoop 2.4.1 using mrv2.

```
public String execute(IHadoopJobConfiguration jobDetails)
        throws HadoopJobException {
    try {

        ArtisanJob job = createJob(jobDetails);
        job.submit();
        return job.getJobID().toString();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | InterruptedException
            | RAnalyticsException | ConfigurationException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to execute job", e);
        throw new HadoopJobException("Unable to execute operation", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HadoopJobException("Unable to execute operation", e);
    }
}
```

...

```
ArtisanJob createJob(IHadoopJobConfiguration details)
        throws IOException, ConfigurationException, RAnalyticsException {

    IOperation mapperOperation =  details.getMapperOperation();
    IOperation reducerOperation = details.getReducerOperation();

    OperationConfiguration conf = new OperationConfiguration();
    conf.setDataProviders(details.getDataProviders());
    conf.setOperationInputs(details.getUserInputs());

    ArtisanJob job = new ArtisanJob(new ArtisanConfiguration());

    // Tell the job to be local for right now
    job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.framework.name", "local");

    job.setMapperClass(ROperationMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ROperationReducer.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(MetricInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(MetricOutputFormat.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(MetricKey.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(MetricWritable.class);
    job.setJarByClass(MetricInputFormat.class);

    job.getConfiguration()
            .set("conf.column",
                    props.getProperty("com.artisan.orchestrator.hbase.metric.colfamily"));

    // Set the output type to hbase so that it will write the outputs to 
    // our hbase server
    MetricOutputFormat.setOutputAdatperType(job.getConfiguration(),
            OutputAdapterType.HBASE);

    // Set the input to be the http service, this needs to be more modular.
    MetricInputFormat.setInputAdapterType(job.getConfiguration(),
            InputAdapterType.HTTP);

    job.setMapperOperation(mapperOperation);
    job.setReducerOperation(reducerOperation);


    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Job class is " + job.getJar());

    return job;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I did not get where can I use the YarnClient APIs to specify the resources required to launch this job (e.g. memory and CPU resources to launch the ApplicationMaster). Did you came across by this stuff before?

Comment: Yes you have to configure it in your mapred-site.xml or you can configure it as I do for the mapreduce.framework.name. This value can be either "local" or "yarn". By default it is configured as yarn in the mapred-site.xml but for testing really quickly I changed it to use local in the job configuration just before submitting. I can update the rest of the answer a bit later.