# How to Run a Hadoop Program Over Network

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

It's the first time I'm trying to work with Hadoop. I'm just trying to work with some example code.

http://www.drdobbs.com/database/hadoop-writing-and-running-your-first-pr/240153197?pgno=2

I have understood the example but i wanna know if this is possible:

I don't have hadoop installed in my computer (it's installed in another computer in my network). I wanna run the jar in my PC but hadoop jobs that my program creates should run on that computer's cluster. Can hadoop be configured like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a mapreduce job from a simple java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with Hadoop in three modes:

- in your local VM (standalone operation)
- in a single-node cluster
- in a multi-node cluster

So, you *can* run your Hadoop jar on your local machine, but you need to have the Hadoop installation there. Please read this [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation) how to configure it.

BTW, the title of your question says "Over Network" and the body says "on my PC". What do you really need?