# Using HBase importtsv tool to bulk load data from Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to bulk load csv file to hbase using `importtsv` and `LoadIncrementalHFiles` tools that ship with Apache HBase.

We can find the tutorials at these pages: [cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/), [apache](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#importtsv.example)

I am using Apache hadoop and hbase.

Both sources explains how to use these tools through command prompt. However I want to get this done from Java code. I know I can write custom map reduce as explained on cloudera page. However I want know if I can use classes corresponding to these tools directly in my Java code.

My cluster is running on Ubuntu VM inside VMWare in pseudo distributed mode, whereas my Java code is running on Windows host machine. When doing it through the command prompt **on the same machine running cluster**, we run following commands:

```
$HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath` ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop jar ${HBASE_HOME}/hbase-server-1.2.1.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2 -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/bulkloadoutputdir datatsv  hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/bulkloadinputdir/
```

As can be seen above we set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. In my case, I guess I have to copy all `xyz-site.xml` hadoop configuration files to my Windows machines and set the directory containing it as `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable. So I copy pasted `core-site.xml, hbase-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml` to my Windows machine, set the directory to Windows environment variable `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. Apart from these I also added all the required JARs to eclipse project's build path.

But after running the project I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:794)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv.createSubmittableJob(ImportTsv.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv.run(ImportTsv.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv.main(ImportTsv.java:747)
    at HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.createStoreFilesFromHdfsFiles(HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.java:36)
    at HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.main(HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader.java:17)
```

So somehow `importtsv` is still not able to find the location of the cluster.

This is how my basic code looks like:

```
1    import java.io.IOException;
2    
3    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
4    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv;
5    import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles;
6    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
7    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
8    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
9    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
10    
11    public class HBaseImportTsvBulkLoader {
12      static Configuration config;
13        
14        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
15          config = new Configuration();
16              copyFileToHDFS();
17          createStoreFilesFromHdfsFiles();
18          loadStoreFilesToTable();
19      }
20        
21        private static void copyFileToHDFS() throws IOException
22        {
23          config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000"); //192.168.23.128       
24          FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
25          Path localfsSourceDir = new Path("D:\\delete\\bulkloadinputfile1");
26          Path hdfsTargetDir = new Path (hdfs.getWorkingDirectory() + "/");       
27          hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(localfsSourceDir, hdfsTargetDir);
28        }
29        
30        private static void createStoreFilesFromHdfsFiles() throws Exception
31        {
32          String[] _args = {"-Dimporttsv.bulk.output=hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/bulkloadoutputdir",
33                  "-Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2",
34                  "datatsv",
35                  "hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/bulkloadinputdir/"};    
36          ImportTsv.main(_args);                                 //**throws exception**
37          
38        }
39        
40        private static void loadStoreFilesToTable() throws Exception
41        {
42          String[] _args = {"hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/hbasebulkloadoutputdir","datatsv"};
43          LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(_args);
44        }
45    }
46
```

**Questions**

1. Which all `xyz-site.xml` fiels are required?
2. In what way should I be specifying `HADOOP_CLASSPATH`?
3. Can I pass the required arguments to `main()` methods of `ImportTsv` such as `-Dhbase.rootdir`below:

   ```
   String[] _args = {"-Dimporttsv.bulk.output=hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/bulkloadoutputdir",
           "-Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2",
           "-Dhbase.rootdir=hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/hbase",
           "datatsv",
           "hdfs://192.168.23.128:9000/bulkloadinputdir/"};
   ```
4. Can I use `ImportTsv.setConf()` to set the same?

Comment: You need to set the zookeeper address. Otherwise it won't know where the partitions are located.

Comment: Where I have to specify the zookeeper address? Should I be specify it in `_args` and pass it to `ImportTsv.main()`?  Or I have to use `ImportTsv.setConf()`? Also currently I am not explicitly running zookeeper. I am using HBase-builtin Zookeeper. (Also for info, I am able to run `importsv` and `LoadIncrementalHFiles` from the command prompt on Ubuntu VM running pseudo distributed cluster and successfully perform bulk load.) I also tried by putting `hbase-site.xml` in `src` folder. Getting same exception.