# Submitting HBase Mapreduce through REST API

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, hbase

I want to submit a map reduce job on HBase using a REST api built on dropwizard.

I have the map reduce jar in S3, created similar to what is given in the example by [HBase itself](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html).

How can I submit this jar on S3 to HBase? Do I need to create a YARN application as shown [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html)?

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: As understood by me you have mapreduce job in s3,  and you want to submit the a mapreduce job from s3(remote client) to HBase cluster (which is installed on hadoop fs).. isnt it? what is dropwizard

Comment: @RamPrasadG: Yes. I want to submit from a web server, not S3. Drop wizard is just a framework to create REST apis. You can discard drop wizard. I just want to submit map-reduce job from REST api.

Comment: yes. Got it. isnt it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program