# Generating bundle of Hadoop program and using it at runtime in Java (Hadoop local mode)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and offer apologies if this is a naive question.

I have a compiled jar version of Hadoop program. I want to run that Hadoop program (the compiled jar bundle) in local mode (from a Java program). I have no idea how can I do that. I could not locate a tutorial which talks about this. The situation is exacerbated by the fact that jar of Hadoop program is created at runtime so I can not add the jar to my dependencies and use that. 
Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: By "Hadoop program", do you mean Spark, MapReduce, or other?

Comment: Map Reduce... sorry for not mentioning this before

Comment: Okay, you run that by `hadoop -jar /path/to/file.jar`. You cannot run it from a Java program, as far as I know.

Comment: Or maybe you are looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849776/calling-a-mapreduce-job-from-a-simple-java-program/9850096#9850096)

Comment: I am not sure if I am right but is it not possible to write a Driver class for handling the job and configuration... more like https://dzone.com/articles/running-hadoop-mapreduce....
Problem is I have generated jar which is generated at runtime...

Comment: It's been over a year since I've needed to run any plain mapreduce code, so I can't really remember. As for the Jar at runtime, how are you achieving that? How would you get those classes onto the classpath after compile time?

Comment: Thanks for the link above. yes you are right, I am looking for the similar thing but I have jar file and don't have access to individual classes and I want to avoid untar and use process.

Comment: I work on a compiler which translates a DSL to hadoop code. So that compiler generates this jar file. All I need is to use that jar file from Java.